# How to replace a specific Word in a Text File in Python?

Tags: python, text, text-files

I know this Question is already answered, but for me the Answers are not working and I dont know why.

First of all this is my Code:

```
c = open('Tasks//Task_Counter.txt', 'r+')
okay = c.read().splitlines()

which_task = int(okay[0])
this_task = which_task + 1 

which_port = int(okay[1])
this_port = which_port + 1

c.truncate(0)
c.close()

c = open('Tasks//Task_Counter.txt', 'r+')
okay = c.read().splitlines()

c.write(str(this_task))
c.write("\n")
c.write(str(this_port))

c.close()

f = open("Tasks//task"+ str(this_task) +".py","w+")
q = open('Tasks//task1.py', 'r+')


for line in q:
    f.write(line)    

f.close()
f = open("Tasks//task"+ str(this_task) +".py","w+")

filedata = f.read()

filedata = filedata.replace('9250', str(this_port))

with open("Tasks//task"+ str(this_task) +".py", 'w+') as file:
  file.write(filedata)

file.close()
f.close()
q.close()
```

The first Part is not really interesting, but the Program is basically just copying a Python Program and and I want to change that Python Program a bit. The Python Program contains that variable:

```
this_browser = "9250"
```

And I want to replace the "9250" with str(this_port). "this_port" is definied as 9260.
Now we come to the Problem. If I run the Program, the new created Python File contains nothing.
Does somebody know how to solve this?

Comment: your `f` and `q` seem a little muddled together. What if Tasks//task1.py contains no rows?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, the Part with f and q does work perfectly fine, in task1.py is of course something written down. The Copying of the Code from "Task1 to Tasks//task"+ str(this_task) +".py" does work aswell, just the replacing not.